# py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.None. Trace:

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to run a Python script on SPARK cluster and below getting error

```
File "create_csv_ecs.py", line 15, in <module>
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
  File "/opt/disk1/spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
  File "/opt/disk1/spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 280, in _ensure_initialized
  File "/opt/disk1/spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 117, in launch_gateway
  File "/opt/disk1/data/hdfs/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/appcache/application_17/container_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 180, in java_import
  File "/opt/disk1/data/hdfs/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/appcache/application_17/container_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.None. Trace:
Authentication error: unexpected command.
```

i am running a simple python to print the hello word like below (IMPORTS are for my actual script)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import csv
import re

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Convert CSV - Python")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


print ("Hello Spark")
```

my SPARK version --

```
spark-submit --version

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, 1.8.0_66
Branch
Compiled by user vanzin on 2018-06-01T20:37:04Z
Revision
Url
Type --help for more information.
```

my SPARK_HOME on local windows machine --

```
SPARK_HOME
C:\Users\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Please help if someone has solved this error i am stuck from last 2 days because of this let me know if more information is required from side to address the this.

Comment: Please, can you provide information about your cluster ? Size ? Machines ? You're on Windows but your stack makes reference to linux paths. `/opt/...`

Answer (score 0):

I got the error it was because of mismatch in the version on my local machine and the SPARK server which i am calling to.

So the fix is i have change the version on my local machine to 2.3.0 which was 2.3.1 before.